# Updating React Flow selected and hover states

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I recently started using react flow it's pretty straightforward to use however I am running into a block trying to update the styles of a selected node.
The only solution I can think of is to useState and update the elements style object for a selected Id.
Is there a way to style selected/focus node state using the style prop?

```
const nodeStyle = {
  padding: '0.7rem',
  height: '7rem',
  width: '12rem',
  borderColor: '#868DA0',
  borderRadius: '3px',
  '&:focus': {                 <----doesn't work
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    color: 'blue',
    padding: '5rem',
    borderRadius: '7px',
  },
}

export default function Flow({ items, itemConnections }: FlowProps) {
  const nodes = items.map(({ id, x_position, y_position, name }) => ({
    id,
    data: {
      label: name
    },
    position: { x: x_position, y: y_position },
    style: nodeStyle,           <------- Styles passed in here
  }))
  return (
    <Box>
      {items.length === 0 ? (
        <EmptyFlowBox />
      ) : (
        <ReactFlow elements={[...nodes, ...itemConnections]}>
          <Controls />
        </ReactFlow>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a style that I apply to react flow.

```
const reactFlowStyle = {
    background: "#e8ecef",
    "& .react-flow__node": {
      "&:hover": {
        boxShadow: "0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)",
      },
    },
  };
```

And then on the grid (using MUI) I applied the style.

```
            <Grid item xs={12} height="80vh" sx={reactFlowStyle}>
              <ReactFlowProvider>
                <ReactFlow
                  elements={elements}
                  nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
                  onElementClick={handleElementClick}
                  onConnect={onConnect}
                  onElementsRemove={onElementsRemove}
                  connectionLineType={"smoothstep" as ConnectionLineType}
                />
              </ReactFlowProvider>
            </Grid>
```